# How to filter and retrieve data from MySQL query result with ansible modules

Tags: jquery, mysql, json, filter, ansible

So, Im trying to filter two dataframes into a same structure as a type host:user, in order to make an host:user comparison. The first one is from my ansible server and the second one is from MySQL server. But I got any issues to filter json data from MySQL query result with [Ansible modules](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html).

Firstly, I tried to retrieve MySQL informations with concat as a JSON:

```
## Compte MySQL
- name: "Get all MySQL accounts"
  community.mysql.mysql_query:
    login_db: mysql
    query: 
    - SELECT user,JSON_ARRAYAGG(concat(host)) as host from user group by user
  register: sql
  tags: [never,test]

- name: Show all MySQL accounts
  debug:
    var: sql
  tags: [never,test]
```

Here is the output:

```
ok: [staging1-sql0] => {
    "sql": {
        "changed": false,
        "executed_queries": [
            "SELECT user,JSON_ARRAYAGG(concat(host)) as host from user group by user"
        ],
        "failed": false,
        "query_result": [
            [
                {
                    "host": "[\"x.xxx.xx.xxx\"]",
                    "user": "username1"
                },
                {
                    "host": "[\"x.xxx.xx.xxx\"]",
                    "user": "username2"
                },
                {
                    "host": "[\"x.xxx.xx.xxx\"]",
                    "user": "username3"
                },
                {
                    "host": "[\"xx.xxx.xx.xxx\", \"xx.x.x.xxx\"]",
                    "user": "username4"
                },
                {
                    "host": "[\"xx.x.x.xxx\"]",
                    "user": "username5"
```

Secondly, I converted the output of MySQL into an item, and select the query_result.

```
- name: Set the MySQL result as an item.
  debug:
    var: item
  loop: "{{ sql | dict2items(key_name='key') }}"
  register: sql_items
  no_log: False
  tags: [never,test]

- name: "Set the dataframe in the same structure host:user"
  set_fact:
    new_sql: "{{ sql_items | community.general.json_query('results[3].{resultats: item.value[0]}') }}"
  tags: [never,test]

- name: Affichage de new_sql
  debug:
    var: new_sql
  tags: [never,test]
```

Here is the output:

```
ok: [staging1-sql0] => {
    "new_sql": {
        "resultats": [
            {
                "host": "[\"x.xxx.xx.xxx\"]",
                "user": "username1"
            },
            {
                "host": "[\"x.xxx.xx.xxx\"]",
                "user": "username2"
            },
            {
                "host": "[\"x.xxx.xx.xxx\"]",
                "user": "username3"
            },
            {
                "host": "[\"xx.xxx.xx.xxx\", \"xx.x.x.xxx\"]",
                "user": "username4"
            },
            {
                "host": "[\"xx.x.x.xxx\"]",
                "user": "username5"
            },
```

Finally, after fitered, I had some problems trying to display data from my ***resultats***  dataframe with ansible modules. For example, in order to display only hosts of each user, I tried this :

```
- name: Display all host names
  debug:
    var: item
  loop: "{{ new_sql | community.general.json_query('resultats[*].host') }}"
  register: query
  tags: [never,test]
```

But it doesnt work, here is the error result :

```
fatal: [staging1-sql0]: FAILED! => {"msg": "Invalid data passed to 'loop', it requires a list, got this instead: . Hint: If you passed a list/dict of just one element, try adding wantlist=True to your lookup invocation or use q/query instead of lookup."}
```

Does anyone of have any idea of how to display those datas with another ansible modules ?

**UPDATE** :

I finally tried this with *map filter* :

```
    - name: New filter with mapping
  debug:
    msg: "{{ new_sql | map(attribute='host') | list }}"
  register: query
  tags: [never,test]
```

But, I got this output :

```
ok: [staging1-sql0] => {
    "msg": "[AnsibleUndefined, AnsibleUndefined, AnsibleUndefined,  AnsibleUndefined, AnsibleUndefined, AnsibleUndefined, AnsibleUndefined....
```

Anyone can help me fix it?

Comment: Hi Mansour, welcome to SO. The `json_query` filter is designed to work with JSON text, but `new_sql.resultats` is a python `list[dict]` so you will want to use the normal [`map` filter](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#map) to work with that data structure within jinja. Good luck

Comment: `loop: "{{ new_sql | community.general.json_query('resultats[*].host') | list }}"`

Comment: @mdaniel I tried to use the map filter, but I think I don't use it correctly. Do you have any exemple that u can show me?

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε I tried but I got this : "Unexpected templating type error occurred on ({{ new_sql | community.general.json_query('resultats[*].host') | list }}): 'NoneType' object is not iterable"

Comment: @MansourNDIAYE you applied the filter to the `new_sql` variable but that is a `dict` containing one key `resultats` containing the `list[dict]` from which you want to map the attribute `hosts`; as I said in my original comment, you'd want `{{ new_sql.resultats | map(attribute='host') | list }}` optionally including `| map('from_json')` to switch those JSON strings to be the actual `list[str]` they encode

Comment: @mdaniel Tried and I got this :
 
`fatal: [staging1-sql0]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'ansible.utils.unsafe_proxy.AnsibleUnsafeText object' has no attribute 'resultats'\n\nThe error appears to be in '/home/mndiaye/ansible/kdata_ansible/roles/mysql-users/tasks/main.yml': line 158, column 3, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n- name: New filter with mapping\n  ^ here\n"}`

Comment: I'm just reporting what the behavior should be based on the `- debug: var=new_sql` you included in your question. No one except you is on your computer with the actual source code, so you'll have to put in some effort on your own